# Android NDK - C++ Exceptions cause crash with 3rd party native library

Tags: android, c++, exception, android-ndk, segmentation-fault

I am having an issue in an android native library I am creating that is dependant on another 3rd party library.

I am using a proprietary Android POS terminal (Android Lollipop API 22).  It comes with a proprietary native library ".so" and I am wrapping that library with my own native code that will be called from Android Java.

The issue I have, is when my code throws a c++ exception that is caught inside the native library (that is, I am not throwing an exception to java) the application crashes with SIGSEGV fatal error at the throw statement.

If I take the 3rd party native library out of the link, I can throw and catch exceptions all I want.  Add back the ".so" library, and any throw causes a crash.

Any idea how to troubleshoot or resolve the issue?

Comment: C++ exceptions unwind the stack.  If the exception tries to unwind a non-C++ frame and that non-C++ frame doesn't play nice with your particular C++ compiler's way of doing stack unwinding, SIGSEGV isn't surprising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, the issue was the third party library.  If a native library is built without exceptions, then code that calls that library also cannot use exceptions.

Very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I might be late for the party, but I've recently faced crashes of the same nature.
In my case it appeared that clang had known issue of compiling libs which are crashing on event of throwing "native" exceptions. I've upgraded my tool-chain, so now it cross-compiled via current-latest "android-ndk-r21".
That did it for me.